# Dart - How run a function after or before each test?

Tags: dart, dart-unittest

I'm using the Dart test package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test

Often, I want to run some function before or after each tests in my test file. Does the test package provide something for this?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

add a `setUp(() { add your code here})` before your `test()` function.
There is also a `tearDown()` which is run after each test.

If you add the setUp function at top level in main it is run for every test, if you put it inside a group it is run for every test in that group. You can have setUp/tearDown on more than one level at the same time.
`tearDown` is executed in any case (like `finally`) no matter if the test fails or succeeds.

Recently `setUpAll()` and `tearDownAll()` was added to do some set up and tear down once before and after all tests.